# Setting the maximum width of a bootstrap slide to the natural width of the image

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

The default settings of the bootstrap4 carousel stretches the slides to fit the entire width of the page regardless of horizontal pixels of the child images. I want the maximum width of the image slide rendered to be the same as the natural width of the image to prevent awkward image quality. I've tried the code below but it isn't working. I'm also using react.

```
$('#carousel-home').on('slide.bs.carousel', function onSlide (ev) {
    let con = document.getElementById('carousel-home')
    console.log(typeof(con))
    con.style.maxWidth = ev.relatedTarget.getElementByTagName('img').naturalWidth
})
```